# is there anyway to create a confirmation popup like this

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am trying to make a popup that can return a true or false to where it was called from when a button is pressed

````
```python
import kivy


def confirmation_popup(title_text):
    btn1 = kivy.uix.button.Button(text="Yes")
    btn2 = kivy.uix.button.Button(text="no")

    btn1.bind(on_release=return True)#to the function itself
    btn2.bind(on_release=return False)

    Boxed_layout= kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout(orientation = "horizontal")
    Boxed_layout.add_widget(btn1)
    Boxed_layout.add_widget(btn2)

    pop = kivy.uix.popup.Popup(title=title_text,content=Boxed_layout)

    pop.open()

if confirmation_popup("are you sure you want to delete your user"):
    #delete user from database```
````

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to get a return from the `Popup`, you should just let the `Popup` call a method that does the confirmed action. If you define your `confirmation_popup` like this:

```
def confirmation_popup(title_text, doit):
    btn1 = Button(text="Yes")
    btn2 = Button(text="no")
    Boxed_layout= BoxLayout(orientation = "horizontal")
    Boxed_layout.add_widget(btn1)
    Boxed_layout.add_widget(btn2)

    pop = Popup(title=title_text,content=Boxed_layout)

    btn1.bind(on_release=partial(doit, pop)) # bind to whatever action is being confiirmed
    btn2.bind(on_release=pop.dismiss)

    pop.open()

# a method that does the action being confirmed
def doit(popup, button):
    popup.dismiss()
    print('do whatever action is confirmed')
```

Then you can use it by:

```
confirmation_popup('This is a Test', doit)
```